# State of network loopback

Tags: linux, networking

Why the state of `lo` interface is reported as `unknown` with `cat /sys/class/net/lo/operstate` even though `ifconfig` says it's running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lo` interface does not support `operstate` (as some other network driver).

The value unknown [is documentated as](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/operstates.txt):

> IF_OPER_UNKNOWN (0):  Interface is in unknown state, neither driver
>   nor userspace has set  operational state. Interface must be considered
>   for user data as  setting operational state has not been implemented
>   in every driver.

See [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=754987#89) for a kernel patch that fixes this.